# Is there a way to check what columns in one dataset exist in another dataset? sql

Tags: sql, dataset, exists

For example, I have table 1 and table 2, is there a way I can check the which columns from table 1 exist in table 2? Thanks!

Comment: Do you just mean which columns share a name, or do you care about matching data type or contents? 

Also, which DBMS are you using? Code to get this kind of metadata is very DBMS-specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While the best solutions will be RDBMS specific (which you have not indicated), a *general* way that's supported by most databases is to use the *information_schema* views, for example the following will list the column names in table1 that are also in table2:

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns t1
where t1.table_schema='schemaName' and t1.table_name='table1'
and exists (
  select * from information_schema.COLUMNS t2
    where t2.column_name = t1.column_name 
      and t2.table_schema = t1.table_schema 
      and t2.column_name ='table2'
);
```